# How to put these buttons on the same line with CSS?

Tags: html, css, button

I have been working on this extension and I am trying to put these buttons in the same place but they look like this. They don't line up

[image: Buttons Don't line Up]

```css
.fversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.sversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: center;
}

.tversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button">2048</a>
<a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button">16384</a>
<a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button">65536</a>
```

I am kind of new to CSS.

Comment: your vertical align properties want to be the same - they are currently invalid - how do you vertically align something horizontally (ie left and right!?)

Comment: When writing questions here, try to keep your material succinct. Instances of "please help me" and "I've been stuck for X hours" are forms of begging and pleading that may earn you downvotes. It is best to stick to stating the question, and describing what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: The use of txtspk is also discouraged in questions, since it makes them harder to read. As a result, this can also attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would abandon the use of float and make them inline-block elements. Also, remove the vertical align - or make them all middle (left and right are not valid values for vertical align)

```css
.fversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
}

.tversion-button {
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button">2048</a>
<a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button">16384</a>
<a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button">65536</a>
```

If you need to split them across the line, you can put them in a flex container:

```css
.container {                         /* flex for even spacing */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* shared styles - could use a class on each button for shared styles instead of repeating (i have just used the extra selector I made from the container) */
.container > a {  
  border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
  background: #8f7a66;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);  
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 0px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button">2048</a>
  <a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button">16384</a>
  <a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button">65536</a>
</div>
```

Comment: idk why but the button in he center is a bit lower than the others kaustavis one worked

Comment: Must be some other styles in your original code that overwrites it - as you can see from both snippets above they are all aligned perfectly

Comment: actually your one works as well bc vertical-align was middle which was wrong i should of wrote center when i was using yours

Comment: thx dude i will use this code bc it puts a space between the buttons

Comment: No worries - vertical align center is invalid - you need to set all to middle - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: hmm this is weird bc when i use middle it connects the buttons but when i use center it adds spaces between the button's

Comment: What happens if you remove it?  May be best to just remove it - that will probably act the same as centre and create less css bloat

Comment: hmm if i remove the code it just does the same thing with the code this was not happening a hour ago. Wow things got realy weird
so i dont need the vertical align code

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example of the issue - I'll have a look and let you know why the vertical thing is happening

Comment: its just weird that when i did not use the vertical align code there was problem a hour ago now i don't use it now it works what

Comment: Ah right, I think the issue was then that you had a couple of elements floated and one not (due to float center) and then you had one vertically aligned middle and 2 to baseline (the invalid left and right default to baseline)

Answer (score 0):

there is **no CSS** like

> float: center

- which is written in ***.sversion-button*** class . you should replace it with

> float: left.

I think it will take the button in the right position which you want.

Comment: dude it works but it does not add a space like petes

Comment: you can add spacing between buttons by adding margin property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove float center and making chnages in html and css,you will get this

```css
.fl1{
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  margin:5px auto;
}
.fl2{
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px auto;
}
.fl3{
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  text-align:right;
  margin:5px auto;
}
.fversion-button {
     border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;


color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }


.sversion-button {
    border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   color: #ffffff;


   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }  


.tversion-button {
    border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   color: #ffffff;


   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="fl1">
<a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button">2048</a>
</div>
<div class="fl2">
       <a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button">16384</a>
</div>
<div class="fl3">
   <a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button">65536</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block;` for tag  `a` and set all buttons to `float:left`

```css
a{
  display:inline-block;
}
.fversion-button {
     border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;


color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: left;
   float: left;
   }


.sversion-button {
    border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   color: #ffffff;


   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: left;
   }  


.tversion-button {
    border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   color: #ffffff;


   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: right;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button">2048</a>
       <a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button">16384</a>
   <a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button">65536</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Replace all css with this one css for all buttons */

.demo_btn {
   border: 2px solid #8f7a66;
   background: #8f7a66;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8f7a66), to(#8f7a66));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66, #8f7a66);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8f7a66 0%, #8f7a66 100%);
   padding: 10px 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add common class to all buttons -->

<a href="2048/index.html" class="fversion-button demo_btn">2048</a>
<a href="16384/index.html" class="sversion-button demo_btn">16384</a>
<a href="65536/index.html" class="tversion-button demo_btn">65536</a>
```